# Using cm/mm on the CSS of a web app that replicates paper interaction is a good practice?

Tags: html, css, w3c

I am building a web application that interact with documents for later printing. In some points is similar to Google Docs. I am considering using cm/mm on the CSS of my documents pages because it will help me on the document generation. Example:

```
// A4 size
.page {
   width: 210mm;
   height: 297mm;
   margin: 2cm 5cm; 
}
```

```
<div class="page">
  ...
</div>
```

What are the main issues of following this approach?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

W3C has a great post on the subject of [CSS units](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html). In particular:

> **cm: Not recommended for screen / recommended for print**
>
> [image]
>
> The so-called absolute units (cm, mm, in, pt and pc) mean the same in CSS as everywhere else. A length expressed in any of these will appear as exactly that size (within the precision of the hardware and software). They are not recommended for use on screen, because screen sizes vary so much. A big screen may be 60cm (24in), a small, portable screen is maybe only 8cm. And you don't look at them from the same distance.
>
> The only place where you could use pt (or cm or in) for setting a font size is in style sheets for print, if you need to be sure the printed font is exactly a certain size. But even there using the default font size is usually better.

Comment: That article is pretty good and I already read that. But my problem is  that I will be using cm/mm not only for printing (e.g. @media print) but for the whole application. But since I want screen and print to be 100% identical I have my doubts that cm/mm is not the best approach.

Comment: so what do you suggest for OP's width and height for a page? We know a dinA4 page is `297mm` big in height. Converting this to pixels because "cm is not recommended" seems very strange.

Comment: @Blauhirn Maybe something relative, like `height: 100%; width: 100%` and then a separate stylesheet for printing.

Comment: Rui said he was creating something similar to Google docs (a print preview app, if you like). Thus, he probably needs to see the proper page dimensions *in the browser*. E.g. so you can see how much space there is left to type into. I really cannot think of another way than using cm dimensions here.

Comment: @Blauhirn The problem I see with that approach is this: let's say we're replicating a spreadsheet program. We decide to make columns 2 inches wide. On a PC with "normal" resolution, that's fine - the app will display maybe 15 columns. On a mobile phone though, a single column will fill the entire screen. Also, the app will look and behave differently across resolutions. Best to stick to `%`'s and have a separate stylesheet for print. The *only* scenario I can think of to use `cm/in` for web would be for something length critical, e.g. a ruler app or similar... IMO.