# Add borders to each printed page with CSS?

Tags: html, css, printing, wkhtmltopdf

Is it possible in CSS or js to emulate the following format in printed media (eg showing borders for each page, with a page number and some text in the corner, with the content nicely split - and not chopped in half)?

[image]

I have been using `page-break-after` to split the content up, but havn't found a way to add this kind of border/page number to each page. This only needs to work in WebKit.

For further information, the reason I am doing this is I am printing HTML documents to PDF using wkhtml.

Comment: You can use a print-only style sheet and just apply an absolute positioned div containing the data you need. Here is a good guide on creating a print style sheet: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: Not really? If it spans more than one page the border will be cut off at the page break...

Comment: If you define its size correctly, the border will never span more than one page. You're essentially just creating an extra div to be used as an overlay when printed. If this div has a static width and height within the print boundaries then it will not get cut off.

Comment: But it will only add to the first page won't it?

Comment: If you only create one div then yes. If you create a div for each page, then you'll be set.

Comment: OK, so how do you know how many pages there will be then?

Comment: I don't know, that depends on your markup and CSS... You'd have to do the math to figure it out, or render the pdf and make note of where the page breaks are. You can use `cm` units in your stylesheet so that you don't have to worry about digital to tangible unit conversion.

Comment: @TimRodham does this helps you. http://jsbin.com/nilepakibuno/1

Comment: This discussion might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html

Comment: any solution as of 2020?