# add border to pages printed using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, css, printing, wkhtmltopdf

similar to this question: [Add borders to each printed page with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639368/add-borders-to-each-printed-page-with-css) how can i print a square border on each page of a multi-page pdf that is rendered using wkhtmltopdf?

i create a html page as a variable, and use snappy: https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy  to render it to a pdf.

```
$html = $this->load->view('print/report_baseline_print',$data,TRUE);

    $snappy = new \Knp\Snappy\Pdf('path to wkhtmltopdf -O landscape');

    $tmp = random_temp_file('.pdf');
    $snappy->generateFromHtml($html,$tmp);
    $filename = 'Baseline-report.pdf';
    $this->output
            ->set_header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate")
            ->set_header("Content-Disposition: filename=$filename;")
            ->set_content_type('application/pdf')
            ->set_output(read_file($tmp));
    delete_file($tmp);
```

I have tried a few things, like:

```
   ....
 <style>
    section:not(:last-child){
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    .box{
        border:1px solid black;
        position:fixed;
        top:10mm;
        right:10mm;
        bottom:10mm;
        left:10mm;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <section id='page1'>
     <div class='box'></div>
   </section>
   <section id='page1'>
     <div class='box'></div>
 ...
```

but the box breaks over the page.
so any ideas how to get a thin black border to print on each page at 10mm margin?
the wkhtmltopdf program seems to be not handling the usual print css properly....

Answer (score 0):

i was nearly there.

just needed to add/change

```
.box{
   border:1pt solid black;
   position:absolute;
   width:28.2cm;
   height:19.3cm;
} 

section{
   position:relative;
}
```

to my css styling within the `<style>` tags

Comment: Thats works if its a 1 page. But the border is not added for multi-pages.