# How to add page border while generating html to pdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, phpwkhtmltopdf

How to add page border for all generated pdf pages from HTML to pdf using `wkhtmltopdf` library?

I tried with

```
div.page
{
    page-break-after: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    border: 5px double !important;
}
```

but no luck.

Simmilar question : [add border to pages printed using wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497556/add-border-to-pages-printed-using-wkhtmltopdf?rq=1)

EDIT :
[image]

Comment: check wkhtmltopdf is patched qt or not. run command 'wkhtmltopdf --version'

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Comment: No, Client postponed this requirement, So stopped working on this.

Answer (score -1):

Simply create an HTML page with below CSS and try to generate pdf file using wkhtmltopdf

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
 body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.border {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 5px double;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  page-break-after: always;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="border"></div>
</body>
</html>
```