# How to add page numbers when printing the document using CSS or javascript/jquery

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add a page numbers when printing the document and I did search on it and I found that we can achieve this using CSS. For this we need to use @page css property. So I have added the following code

```
@page {
  /*margin-top: 15mm;*/
  margin-bottom: 25mm;
  margin-left: 30mm;
  margin-right: 30mm;

  @bottom-center {
  counter-increment: page;
  counter-reset: page 1;
      content: "page " counter(page);
  }
}
```

But I am facing the one problem, the above mentioned properties all are applied but my page numbers are not displaying. I don't know why its happening.

Can anyone facing the same issue? or anyone know the solution,please help out to fix this issue.

Comment: might be helpful for you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html

Comment: Actually I looked into it and just pasted the code but this is work only if you have static id or class of element, in my case I have dynamic data and I don't know what elements are coming

Comment: you can use `ID` see the example.  http://jsbin.com/kewepowedu/1/edit

Comment: let me know if the solution doesn't work for you. or you find any better solution.

Comment: I don't know the ID,.... we have a dynamic conent

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

content: counter(page)

```
@page {
    @bottom-left {
        content: counter(page);
     }
 }
```