# css insert page number on print page

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

Currently I doing a print page by using `<thead>` and `<tbody>`, since the  will display on every page. I would like to insert a page number into  like "Page 1/2". After I googled and looking for stackoverflow, the solution css already not work for currently browser. The code like this

```
@page {
    counter-increment: page;
    counter-reset: page 1;
    @top-right {
        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
    }
}
```

So I am looking for the latest solution for insert page number into print page. Hope your all can share your approach no matter in css, javascript, jquery or html. Thank You!
PS: Please don't tell me using print dialog setting to display page number

Reference:
[print page count with total number of pages using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654071/print-page-count-with-total-number-of-pages-using-css)

[IE and Edge: Print page numbers on pages when printing html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569528/ie-and-edge-print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html)

[Add Page number using Page Property of CSS for each printed pages from asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913468/add-page-number-using-page-property-of-css-for-each-printed-pages-from-asp-net-c)

[Page numbers with CSS/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109893/page-numbers-with-css-html)

[Browser Support for CSS Page Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797161/browser-support-for-css-page-numbers)

Comment: Try this: [How to number print pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43768942/6557304)