# How to insert the number into the bottom right of each page by TWIG and CSS

Tags: css, twig

I'm a newbie in TWIG. But I have to resolve some trouble with the page numbering.
I have the follow TWIG template

```
{% extends 'agreement/report_base_template.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Personal card{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% for Person in AllPersons %}
{% set pageNum = 1 %}
<div id="content" class="page">
<!-- generate the frist page as a table //-->
<div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
</div>
{% set pageNum = pageNum + 1 %}
<div id="content" class="page">
<!-- generate the second page as a table //-->
<div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
</div>
<!-- other pages generated the same way //-->
{% endfor %}    
{% endblock %}
```

That template generates the multi-page documents for each `Person`.
UPD: added after 20 mins
There is the need to insert the number into the bottom right of each page as it's shown below.
[image]
And for each document, the number of the first page must be 1.

UPD: added after 7 hours
The use of JavaScript is also possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD: Added on May 5th**
I've finished my work with the next solving which was compiled from some other answers:

1. [Print page numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html#20317775)
2. [Relative position into the parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487292/position-absolute-but-relative-to-parent#10487329)

Now, I can see the numbers on the each page.
**IMPORTANT

This solution doesn't show the total number of pages.

See at the end of this post how to display the total number of the pages.**

I changed the TWIG template

```
{% for Person in AllPersons %}
    {% set pageNum = 1 %}
    <div class="page">
        <div class="content">
            <!-- there is some the content of the first page //-->
        </div>
    <div class="break">{{pageNum}}</div>
    </div>
    {% set pageNum = pageNum + 1 %}
    <div class="page">
        <div class="content">
            <!-- there is some the content of the second page //-->
        </div>
    <div class="break">{{pageNum}}</div>
    </div>
    <!-- other pages generated the same way //-->
{% endfor %}
```

and CSS

```
.page {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  position: relative;
}
.content {
    padding: 0.5cm 1cm 0.5cm 2cm;
}
.break{
    page-break-after: always;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5mm;
    right: 5mm;
}
.break:before{
    white-space: nowrap; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;  
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);  
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

**UPD: Added after 4 hours**
To display the total number of the pages, I used the next script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".person").each( function(){
        var totalNumber = $(this).children(".page").length;
        $(this).children(".page").each( function (index){
           $(this).children(".break").append("page "+(index+1)+" of "+ totalNumber);
        })
    })
});
```

And a little bit, I changed the TWIG template

```
{% for Person in AllPersons %}
    {% set pageNum = 1 %}
    <div class="person"> <!-- This tag was addaed //-->
        <div class="page">
```

Comment: You also can use the table layout by inserting the follow lines in CSS
   `.page {  display: block;` and `.break{
 display: table-footer-group;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what do you mean by page numbering, but if I have to guess from your code snippet you want to replace the `pageNum` variable and if you read the twig documentation carefully you'll find [The loop variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable)

here's an example:

```
{% for Person in AllPersons %}
    Person #{% loop.index %}
{% endfor %}
```

this will print:

```
Person #1
Person #2
```

and so on for each iteration