# Oracle Apex Report - Adding page number while printing

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex

I have a button which does a window.print() that prints out an Oracle APEX classic report, and I am just wondering if there is any way to add a page number while printing?

I added the following CSS code to the html header section of the region, which doesn't seem to work.

```
<style media="print" type="text/css">
div#pageFooter:after  
{
 counter-increment: page;  
 content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
}  
</style>
```

It printed out "Page 1 of 0" only on the first page.

Comment: This might give a way forward: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html

Comment: I did try this but it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure. The counter(pages) returned 0. I found out other people ran into the same issue as well on Google, and haven't found a solution yet.