# How to add sequential page number at header in Xpages applications while printing

Tags: css, xpages

I build a Xpage application through Lotus designer 9 . I have a header through CSS which prints at each page while printing. I want to add page number of each page at header in this format (i.e. Page 1 of 6 )
 can any one guide ?

Comment: Maybe this will work better. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20317775

Comment: Thanks @Jesper , the link is useful

Comment: Can some one fix my problem . counter(pages) always returns 0 at every page

Answer (score 5):

Try this CSS:

```
@page {
    @top-center {
        content: 'Page ' counter(page) ' of ' counter(pages);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great CSS only solution!

Comment: Thanks @EricMcCormick 

Answer (score 0):

HTML printing in a browser is a PITA. If you want to get quality output, you might consider to generate some PDF that users can print. It's a lot more work, but gives you 100% control how the print will look like.

You can check my blog series on [Domino and PDF](http://www.notessensei.com/blog/2012/04/extracting-data-from-domino-into-pdf-using-xslt-and-xslfo-part-1.html) to get a head start.

Short of that Per's & Eric's answer is the way to go