# CSS @page doesn't display content in @top-center, @bottom-right, etc

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to generate a print-ready HTML file and therefore started working with CSS `@page` and everything around it. One big problem I'm facing is that I can't manage to display page numbers using `@bottom-right` and all similar solutions. Do you know if there could be a general reason behind it (like it's deprecated, etc.), as I've tested even the simplest solutions like:

```
@page {
  @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page);
  }
}
```

and still nothing seems to make the pagination or any other content appear.

Comment: Did you put this into `@media print  { .. }`?

Comment: Yep, forgot to mention, tried both with media print and media all :/

Comment: Ehm, CanIUse doesn't even list `@bottom-right`, so I'm not sure if many browsers support it yet.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but it sounds similar: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html)

Comment: I had a similar issue and I found this article illuminating: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/

Answer (score 2):

What are you using to render this? A lot of browsers don't have proper support for print CSS, so it might be better to use something specifically built for it, like [weasyprint](https://weasyprint.org/).