# Adding page numbers in CSS to "html to pdf" converter

Tags: css

I'm using modified by my team PHP tool for converting HTML to PDF. My task is to add number of pages in bottom corner. I never know how many pages I'll have, I don't know after which part I may get a page break.

I can't use Javascript.

I was thinking about using CSS counter, but I have no idea if it's good way, how can I check if page had a break...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print page numbers on pages when printing html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
#pageFooter {
    display: table-footer-group; 
}

#pageFooter:after {
    counter-increment: page;
    content: counter(page); 
}
```

From [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20317775/11454689)