# Add page counter to print page CSS with @page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

It happens that I have an HTML page that will be printed. I wanted to add a page counter and was trying to use `@page` for that. But then, I noticed that `@page` was not working at all in Internet Explorer. It works in Chrome, though. Everything except the `content` property, that doesn't show.

Here's the code

```
@page {
        size: auto; /* auto is the current printer page size */
        margin: 10%; /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
        @bottom-center{
            font-family: FlamaSemicond-Basic;
            font-size: 10pt;
            color: black;
            content: "Hello!";
        }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I was looking at this one . I have not tested it but let me know your feedback . this is a solution for the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html    and this one is to fiddle and see the css key value for the  counter-increment implementaiton on screen not printer  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp

Comment: Hello! I tried that solution. I've added the "counter-increment" in every element I saw fitting and am writing the page number on a fixed footer, but the value doesn't change from one page to another.

Comment: Use different browser and see if there is a difference. Also can you post a simple running code which really helps

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue: using Chrome 79.  Here it says (I think?) that '@page' is (mostly) supported by Chrome - https://caniuse.com/#search=%40page

And this gives an example:   https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-3/
(their Example number 12 shown below).

> The following style sheet establishes a page header containing the
>   title ("Hamlet") on the left side and the page number, preceded by
>   "Page ", on the right side:
>
> @page {   size: 8.5in 11in;   margin: 10%;
>
> @top-left {
>       content: "Hamlet";   }   @top-right {
>       content: "Page " counter(page);   } }

When I test it - Chrome obeys the page size, but doesnt show the page numbers.