# Number page with css

Tags: css

I'm trying to insert page number of my html document so that it appears in the pdf print.
I use this css code but it doesn't work for me:

```
@page {
 @bottom-center {
  content: counter(page);
 }
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: This code requires polyfill library https://www.pagedjs.org/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print page numbers on pages when printing html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html)

Comment: @Justinas unfortunately no...

Answer (score 0):

The below code might help as the counter increment property increases the countfor each occurence

```css
@page{
  @bottom-center
  {
    counter-increment:page;
    counter : counter(page);
  }
}
```