# Printing Page Numbers on Google Chrome 2022

Tags: css

I am trying to add page numbers to a document so when we print, it will say Page 1 of 15 for example.

This is my code now.

```
<STYLE TYPE="text/css"> 
P.breakhere {page-break-before: always} } 
#content 
{ display: table; } 

tfoot{ display: table-footer-group; } 

@page { @bottom-right { content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages); } } 

</STYLE> 

{% for line in line_items %} 

<P CLASS="breakhere"> 

Content is here 

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60857567/7941251

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print page numbers on pages when printing html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html)