# Set header and footer on the printed PDF using CSS3 @page rule

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing

Why doesn't this work?

> I want use the `@page` rule not `@media print`

```css
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 10%;
  @bottom-center {
    content: "Page " counter(page);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi nam assumenda magni, minima, odit cumque eveniet impedit in vel quasi accusamus fugit reiciendis vitae, consectetur aspernatur error quas dolore possimus.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

> I am using Google Chrome Version 114.0.5735.134 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html I suggest you look here.

Comment: @MecitYücetürk thanks for the good link. but most of the participations are old (the latest is in 2019). and most of the solutions suggest alternatives to `@page` rule. I at least need to know if what I am trying to accomplish is supported by browsers and if yes then how to get it to work.

Comment: I believe that when you try to generate a PDF from an HTML document, the PDF viewer typically does not interpret the CSS rules defined in the `@page` rule. Only the styles in the `@media print` rule, because these styles are specifically intended for printing.

Comment: @ninadepina but the margin from `@page` works. Even the docs I have seen state that `@page` works on print pages.