# The @page style for top-left top-right etc is not working

Tags: html

I've the following example page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Print Example</title>
    <style>
        @page {
            size: 8.5in 11in;
            margin: 10%;

            @top-left {
                content: "Hamlet";
            }
            @top-right {
                content: "Page " counter(page);
            }
        }

        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hamlet - Sample Page</h1>
    <p>
        Hamlet is one of William Shakespeare's most famous plays.
        This is a sample page to demonstrate the header and page number.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

When the page is printed, I want the top left to have the content "Hamlet" and the top right to have the page count. But this not working. For further reference [visit](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/).

The page rule grammar seems not to work in the latest Chrome and edge browsers. Is there something that I'm doing wrong? How can I get this to work?

Comment: I'm afraid `@top-left` and `@top-right` are not supported. Did you try to instead add rules in `@page` that will conditionally add pseudo-elements on the body element by doing `body::before{}` and `body::after{}` that will hold those two contents? Then for positioning them you may add `position: fixed;` and `top:`/`left:` coords.

Comment: Indeed @top-left and @top-right are not yet implemented. I did not try adding conditional rules to `@page`. I shall do it.

Comment: to be more clear, I meant something like `body::before { content: "Hamlet";position: fixed;top: 1em;left: 1em; }` inside a `@media print`. The tricky part was the page counter inside the next `body::after { content: "Page " counter(page);position: fixed;top: 1em;right: 1em; }`. The counter doesn't work. So you need a different approach: [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html) a SO question with several suggestions about that including [pagedjs](https://pagedjs.org/documentation/2-getting-started-with-paged.js/)