# Milimeters are not always the same

Tags: css, grid, alignment, absolute

I need to draw background grid and place divs on that grid. Div edges must be aligned to grid. All positions and dimmensions must be calculated in millimeters. Unfortunately, divs has some offset from grid, are not aligned.

I even tried background grid image instead of drawing grid in css - does not help.
(fiddle tested in google chrome)

http://jsfiddle.net/amqu1zrb/

html:

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="widget widget1"></div>
    <div class="widget widget2"></div>
    <div class="widget widget3"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}

.bg {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100mm;
    height: 100mm;
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(lightgray 1px, transparent 1px), 
        linear-gradient(90deg, lightgray 1px, transparent 1px); 
    background-size: 5mm 5mm;
    position: relative;
}

.widget {
    width: 10mm;
    height: 10mm;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}

.widget1 {
    top: 5mm;
    left: 5mm;
}

.widget2 {
    top: 35mm;
    left: 55mm;
}

.widget3 {
    top: 45mm;
    left: 85mm;
}
```

Any ideas how to align divs to grid precisely?

Comment: I think you should convert all measurements to px. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16297686/1238244

Comment: You can't use millimeters reliably. Different screen sizes have different numbers of pixels per millimeter, and not every browser will know the conversion.

Comment: What about printing? I want to print the document and have 1mm = 1mm. Should I convert px's to mm's back?

Comment: Millimeters don’t work reliably in print either (though there is less variation than on screen).