# Highcharts: converting millimeters to pixel

Tags: highcharts, pixel

Hello to the community,

I would have one more question on Highcharts. I am working closely with designers and they prefer to have charts given to them with a predefined height, width, and text size, in millimetres (not pixels). That is because ultimately these charts are going to be printed out in reports.

Right now designers enter the value they want for a specific chart in millimetres onto a spreadsheet, and I convert all that to px before making the chart.

To convert pixel to mm I use:
px = mm * DPI / 25.4 since 1in = 25.4 mm.

For point (pt) to pixel I use:
px = pt * DPI/72 since 1pt = 1/72th of 1in.

Where DPI is a variable given to me: usually 300.

However the font size tends to be much bigger than it should be (it looks like it is 20 pt on the chart when I want 12 pt), and the chart dimensions also seem to be wrong.

My first question: do my calculations look right? (I am afraid I am not much of an image expert).
My second question: would there be a way to specify chart dimensions in a different format than pixel when configuring a chart on Highcharts, by any chance?

Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

- You can use some of the already existing converters to get those values, like: https://www.unitconverters.net/typography/millimeter-to-pixel-x.htm
- You can use CSS to set parameters for the container that the chart is rendered inside, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vu41gdt6/

  ```
  #container {
     height: 15rem;
     width: 15rem;
  }
  ```
- Consider use regular CSS units for the charts on you web app and change them only for printing needs.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.beforePrint

Useful article: [Using cm/mm on the CSS of a web app that replicates paper interaction is a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297619/using-cm-mm-on-the-css-of-a-web-app-that-replicates-paper-interaction-is-a-good)