# How to make items occupy space following an order

Tags: html, css, angular, css-grid

I have a html and this HTML has two childrens' HTML. On the parent HTML I have a div called .page that's a big area where the children need to occupy. Both children have the same size, and I need them to spawn in a order; so let's say the first child component will spawn in the 1 position (like in the image below), and the other need to follow the order, if has space on the left to occupy, then does it, if not, occupy the space below the element on the left?

How needs to be:

[image]

How is working right now:

[image]

The CSS:

```
.page {
  display: flex;
  width: 26.4cm;
  height: 37cm;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Children's grid:

```
.displayGridSlip {
  display: grid;
  width: 13cm;
  grid-template-columns: 13cm;
  grid-template-rows: 1.7cm 4.9cm 0.5cm;
  grid-template-areas:
    "h"
    "b"
    "f";
  border-bottom-style: dashed;
  border-bottom-width: 0.3mm;
  border-right-style: dashed;
  border-right-width: 0.3mm;
  padding-top: 0.2cm;
}
```

Main html code

```
<div *ngFor="let itemCapa of arraySlips.capa; let k = index;">
    <div class="page">
        <app-slip-capa [itemCapa]="itemCapa"></app-slip-capa>
        <app-slip-conteudo [item]="arraySlips.info" [itemCapa]="itemCapa"></app-slip-conteudo>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your html code

Comment: Added the main html code

Answer (score 0):

I think that using the .page class in the div after the *ngFor one is wrong because in this way you are using all the 26cm width for each element and not half of that.
I'm not sure this is the answer you are looking for but try using .page at the start of the div tree and then col-6 on the *ngFor div so that it will use only half of the the column width for each element:

```
    <div class="page">
        <div class="col-6" *ngFor="let itemCapa of arraySlips.capa; let k = index;">
            <div class="">
                <app-slip-capa [itemCapa]="itemCapa"></app-slip-capa>
                <app-slip-conteudo [item]="arraySlips.info" [itemCapa]="itemCapa"></app-slip-conteudo>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also, i'm not sure that using centimeters is correct (see this answer about that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16297686/8003673 ), but try as you want. If it's wrong, try using other dimension.
If you try something like the code below, it will work as you want, using half of the page dimension for each element:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 div-to-the-left" *ngFor="let i of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; let k = index;">
                    <div class="">
                        <span>test {{i}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```